# How to populate an array from a .txt file in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

So a bit on the background:

I have a VC, with a textField, when pressed, the user is segued to a tableView controller. The idea is, they need to tell me the country they are from. So I currently have an array, which holds some countries in, and then this is populated into the tableView. All works fine. But, I need to display all the countries, and as there are like 196 countries, i thought it would be silly to have an array with 196 countries in.

Is there a way i can create a .txt file with all the countries in, and then populate the array from this .txt file? I have made a file called: Countries.txt and it's currently blank.

1. How do I write the list of countries in the .txt file? e.g. "France" "Spain" "United Kingdom" "United States" - do I need to use a comma to separate them?
2. What code do I need to write in the tableViewController.swift to make this work?
3. Or, is there a better way I can do this?

Thanks in advance, I'm very new to swift so please go easy :)

My code for tableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet var tabeView: UITableView!

var countryPicker = ["Colombia", "England", "France", "Germany", "Brazil", "Austria", "Spain", "Australia", "USA", "Berlin", "Thailand", "Northern Ireland", "New Zealand", "Hawaii", "Switzerland", "Sweeden", "Finland", "Turkey", "Russia", "Netherlands", "Japan"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    countryPicker.sort(){$0 < $1}

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return countryPicker.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = countryPicker[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. As rounak says in his answer, NSArray includes methods for saving and loading contents to a "plist" file. That has the advantage that if you open the file with Xcode, it shows the array in a nicely formatted editor.

Those methods only work if the array and everything contained inside it are all "property list objects." (dictionaries, arrays, strings, numbers (integer and float), dates, binary data, and Boolean values).

Property lists are not so good for reading and writing outside of Xcode however. The internal file format is fairly nasty-looking XML. It's also possible to save plists to a binary format that is fast and space-efficient, but CAN'T be read with a text editor.

You could also save your list of countries with a separate line for each country, then read the contents in as a String (using an NSString method like `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error`. Then you'd use the NSString method `componentsSeparatedByString` (passing in "\n", or line break, as the separator string) to break your long string into an array of strings. Doing it that way has the advantage that the file is a simple text file that can be viewed/edited with any text editor. (As long as it's from a platform that uses the same character sequence for line breaks, but that's another story)

There are other options like JSON and XML, but I'm not going to go into those here.

Comment: Note that with the advent of the Codable protocol, that is really the preferred way to do this now. You can easily use Codable to serialize/deserialize your array as JSON or even as a plist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
+ (NSArray<ObjectType> * nullable)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString * nonnull)aPath
```

and

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString * nonnull)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

Comment: Hi, Is this Swift? If not, could you show me this in Swift if possible and how to place it in my code? thanks

Comment: It is the new Objective-C syntax for Swift interoperability. The Swifties were not happy enough without making what used to be clear Objective-C trashy.

Comment: @Nick89 No it's Objective C with generics and nullability.